# Rails Jquery Autocomplete with JSON fails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, autocomplete

I am attempting to use a remote service to populate an autocomplete field that I have in rails. It is supposed to query and return available employees by last name

I have an action in my controller called employeeAutocomplete which gathers data from an outside database:

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
 def employeeAutocomplete
  @banner = employeeSearch(params[:term])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @banner.to_json }
  end
 end
```

In my routes.rb I have a placeholder route:

```
match '/banner/cheese' => 'services#employeeAutocomplete'
```

I can successfully browse to http://0.0.0.0:3000/banner/cheese.json?term=mac and receive an array such as the following with employee data:

```
[ {"LAST_NAME": "MacDougal", "FIRST_NAME": "Elaine", "TITLE": "Internet Technician"}, {"LAST_NAME": "MacCallum", "FIRST_NAME": "Harvey", "TITLE": "Systems Architect"} ]
```

However, this does not work with the autocomplete field. Here's the javascript for my view:

```
$("#service_employeeLast").autocomplete({
    source: "/banner/cheese.json"
});
```

I receive an error in the firebug console:
[image: I receive an error in the firebug console]

I'm at wits end. I do not know what I'm doing wrong, I've tried two different autocomplete plugins and keep getting this same error jquery.js:8103

Help!

Comment: Can you show the whole text of the error that appears in the JavaScript console?

Comment: That is it. It says GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/banner/cheese.json?term=mcc and then it says jquery.js:8103 Here is an [image](http://i.imgur.com/CRn6Z.png)

Comment: I've even just modified the json it returns to fit the "label", "value" keys and that has made zero difference. I can still access the url through the web browser, but javascript acts like its inaccessible. If I paste the generated array directly into the source: it works! Something is wrong with the routing here. Why can't the backend js access the url like I can?

Comment: Can you do an AJAX request without the autocomplete stuff? So `$.get('/banner/cheese.json', function (data, status, xhr) {console.log(data);})`

Comment: I added a term request so it would hopefully return something `$.get('/banner/cheese.json?term=mcc', function (data, status, xhr) {console.log(data);})` and received the same message as the image above in the comment.

Comment: When I do rake routes, it exists!! `GET    /banner/cheese(.:format)                           services#employeeAutocomplete` no idea what's going on here.

Comment: 1) remove "respond_to do ..." and check what will happen; 2) in firebug console, check the request headers, what's "Accept"?

Comment: Believe it or not, it was CHROME causing the issue. Apparently chrome dislikes localhost ajax requests!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not it was Google Chrome causing the issue. Apparently it dislikes localhost ajax calls. Here is the updated code working as intended:

services.js

```
$(function() {
 $( "#service_employeeLast" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/banner/fetch",
    minLength: 2,

 });
});
```

services_controller

```
def employeeAutocomplete
    @banner = employeeSearch(params[:term])
    @banner_hash = []
    @banner.each do |b|
        @banner_hash << { 
            :title => b["POSITION_TITLE"], 
            :label => [b["FIRST_NAME"], b["LAST_NAME"]].join(" "), 
            :value => b["LAST_NAME"], 
        }
    end
    render :json => @banner_hash
end
```

The key here also that your return value hash has a label and value key/value pair

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you encoded the data twice with `render :json => @banner.to_json`. It should be `render :json => @banner`, and the data will be encoded automatically.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Didn't seem to make a difference though :(